# Mail class not using correct "from" in email

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a class that extends Mailable where I use in it :

```
return $this->subject($this->email->subject . ' | ' . $this->email->name)
            ->from($this->email->email, $this->email->name)
            ->replyTo($this->email->email, $this->email->name)
            ->to('XXX@gmail.com')
            ->view('guest.mail');
```

This is just the classic way of sending an email. The problem I'm having is that in Gmail I get a weird message that has the `from` field not using `$this->email->email` but rather using `XXX@gmail.com` (which is also my `MAIL_USERNAME` field in my `.env`).

I have no idea why. The reply to is working correctly, subject as well. It's just that the from in the email I get looks as if it was sent by `XXX@gmail.com` for no logical reason to me.

Any idea what would be the issue? Did anyone ever come across an issue like that with Gmail?

Comment: Gmail override whatever value you have set with default values

Comment: Why would it overwrite the default from value to the current email? Do you have a source? Any idea on how to go around this? @FouedMOUSSI

Comment: In the case of google SMTP, the from address won't change even if you give this in the mail class. This is due to google mail's policy, and not a Laravel issue. Thought I will share it here.